# TurfJs interpolation with leftlet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, turfjs

I am trying to reproduce this code https://codepen.io/lknarf/pen/JXybxX but using leaflet instead of mapbox before I can start using my own data.

In the code it is adding the intersection, points, boundaries, isobands and grid as geoJSONs but when I try to use L.geoJSON(intersection).addTo(map) it says Invalid GeoJSON object.

How can I add this features to leaflet? I tried doing it with plugin leaflet-contour but also didn't work

```
    let boundaries = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            name: "boundaries",
            crs: { type: "name", properties: { name: "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
            features: [
                {
                    type: "Feature",
                    properties: {},
                    geometry: {
                        type: "MultiPolygon",

                        coordinates: [[[[41.376, 110.763], [41.381, 110.823], [41.357, 110.815], [41.317, 110.944], [41.346, 110.978], [41.299, 111.026], [41.285, 111.085], [41.306, 111.096], [41.238, 111.232], [41.289, 111.273], [41.327, 111.439], [41.309, 111.724], [41.252, 111.833], [41.216, 111.822], [41.204, 111.862], [41.129, 111.874], [41.046, 112.027], [41.003, 112.011], [40.968, 112.035], [40.938, 112.138], [40.818, 112.178], [40.761, 112.144], [40.738, 112.086], [40.697, 112.124], [40.657, 112.108], [40.654, 112.038], [40.587, 112.092], [40.559, 112.046], [40.448, 112.218], [40.391, 112.259], [40.354, 112.229], [40.356, 112.264], [40.253, 112.305], [39.795, 111.964], [39.611, 111.925], [39.619, 111.829], [39.588, 111.777], [39.643, 111.64], [39.663, 111.511], [39.642, 111.43], [39.67, 111.435], [39.721, 111.358], [39.789, 111.366], [39.896, 111.439], [40.044, 111.405], [40.151, 111.308], [40.27, 111.039], [40.31, 111.024], [40.33, 111.108], [40.382, 111.121], [40.495, 110.953], [40.483, 110.895], [40.534, 110.837], [40.585, 110.874], [40.611, 110.796], [40.79, 110.78], [40.805, 110.705], [40.917, 110.739], [40.941, 110.623], [41.053, 110.672], [41.1, 110.639], [41.164, 110.65], [41.224, 110.554], [41.261, 110.559], [41.291, 110.512], [41.288, 110.547], [41.331, 110.569], [41.31, 110.629], [41.385, 110.719], [41.376, 110.763]]]]
                    }
                }
            ]
        };


        let points = turf.randomPoint(30, { bbox: turf.bbox(boundaries) });

        turf.featureEach(points, function (currentFeature, featureIndex) {
            currentFeature.properties = { value: (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(2) };
        });
        console.log(points);

        var interpolate_options = {
            gridType: "points",
            property: "value",
            units: "degrees",
            weight: 10
        };
        let grid = turf.interpolate(points, 0.05, interpolate_options);
        grid.features.map((i) => (i.properties.value = i.properties.value.toFixed(2)));

        var isobands_options = {
            zProperty: "value",
            commonProperties: {
                "fill-opacity": 0.8
            },
            breaksProperties: [
                { fill: "#e3e3ff" },
                { fill: "#c6c6ff" },
                { fill: "#a9aaff" },
                { fill: "#8e8eff" },
                { fill: "#7171ff" },
                { fill: "#5554ff" },
                { fill: "#3939ff" },
                { fill: "#1b1cff" },
                { fill: "#1500ff" }
            ]
        };
        let isobands = turf.isobands(
            grid,
            [1, 10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 100],
            isobands_options
        );

        boundaries = turf.flatten(boundaries);
        isobands = turf.flatten(isobands);

        let features = [];

        isobands.features.forEach(function (layer1) {

            boundaries.features.forEach(function (layer2) {
                let intersection = null;
                try {
                    intersection = turf.intersect(layer1, layer2);
                } catch (e) {
                    layer1 = turf.buffer(layer1, 0);
                    intersection = turf.intersect(layer1, layer2);
                }
                if (intersection != null) {
                    intersection.properties = layer1.properties;
                    intersection.id = Math.random() * 100000;
                    features.push(intersection);
                }
            });
        });

        let intersection = turf.featureCollection(features);

        var container = L.DomUtil.get("map")


        if (container != null) {
            container._leaflet_id = null;
        }
        var map = L.map("map").setView([41.376, 110.763], 11);

        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',

        }).addTo(map);


        L.geoJSON(intersection).addData(map)
```